# pass value to IBAction

Tags: ios, uitapgesturerecognizer

I will be fast.
I have 6 images,with 6 gestures attached to them and one IBAction. I want each gesture to pass a parameter to the action so i dont have to write 6 separate actions.Here is my code:

```
    oneImage =[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"one.gif"]];
    two Image=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"two.gif"]];
    +4 more images

     UITapGestureRecognizer *oneGest=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(insertChar:)];
         UITapGestureRecognizer *twoGest=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(insertChar:)];
    +4 more gestures


    -(IBAction)insertChar:(id)sender
    {

    textfield.text = [textfield.text stringByAppendingString:@" PASS HERE VALUE FROM GESTURE,"ONE","TWO",etc "];
    }
```

Comment: the sender is id, it can take any form. Or you can typecast it to `(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender` and use it

Comment: This has nothing to do with Xcode.

Comment: ok H2CO3 if that was a huge mistake then i deeply sorry! :(

Comment: I bet it's not as fast as googling for `UITapGestureRecognizer sender` which gives us this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6085617/792677

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to pass arbitrary data to the `insertChar:` method. The `sender` will be the gesture recognizer. Here's one possible solution:

```
oneImage =[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"one.gif"]];
oneImage.tag = 1;
twoImage=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"two.gif"]];
twoImage.tag = 2;
// +4 more images

UITapGestureRecognizer *oneGest=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(insertChar:)];
UITapGestureRecognizer *twoGest=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(insertChar:)];
// +4 more gestures

-(IBAction)insertChar:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    static NSString *labels[6] = { @"ONE", @"TWO", ... @"SIX" };
    UIView *view = sender.view;
    NSInteger tag = view.tag;
    NSString *label = labels[tag - 1]; // since tag is 1-based.

    textfield.text = [textfield.text stringByAppendingString:label];
}
```

Comment: i'll try and will get back with you.

Comment: It worked!! Thank you very much! One hint from me too: oneImage.tag should be 0,twoImage.tag=1 etc.

Comment: It's best not to use 0 as a tag value since that is the default value for all views. I updated my answer's code to reflect the fact that the `tag` is 1-based.

Answer (score 0):

You need to somehow link the 'sender' value that you get as parameter in `-(IBAction)insertChar:(id)sender` with the `UIImageView`s you create.

The action method will look like this:

```
-(IBAction)insertChar:(id)sender
{

 UIGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = (UIGestureRecognizer*)sender;
 UIView *view = gestureRecognizer.view;
//do whatever you want with the view that has the gestureRecgonizer's event on

}
```

Then you can link your view in different ways. One way is to use the tag property.

Comment: The `sender` for `insertChar:` will be the gesture recognizer, not the image view.